# I get errors using codeigniter email library

Tags: codeigniter, email

Although emails are sent successfully, I get a list of errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mail(/var/log/php-mail.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1553
```

and:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at system/core/Exceptions.php:185)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 675
```

and:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at system/core/Exceptions.php:185)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 542
```

What's wrong with my code?! Is there anything I can do about this?!

Comment: do you have the correct permissions to read, and also are you updating the header(s) after sending?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a **mail.log** entry in your **php.ini** file which should log all the **mail()** function calls. For more check what **phpinfo()** is saying about **mail.log**.